# Is there a way to force the Apple Number Keypad?

Tags: objective-c, keyboard, ios11

I recently upgraded my app, and had one weird bug report from a user using the WordFlow keyboard.  This didn't used to happen, but now when this keyboard pops out, it pushes my view off the screen.

I would just like to always use the number pad for these fields as they only take numbers.

My storyboard is set up this way:

```
<textInputTraits key="textInputTraits" keyboardType="numberPad" keyboardAppearance="alert" returnKeyType="next" enablesReturnKeyAutomatically="YES"/>
```

When the Keyboard shows I offset the view as follows

```
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize.height, 0.0);
    UIScrollView *scrollView = (UIScrollView *)[self view];
    scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

    kbHeight = kbSize.height;

    CGRect aRect = self.view.frame;
    aRect.size.height -= kbSize.height;
    if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, self.activeField.frame.origin) ) {
        keyboard = TRUE;
        scrollView.frame = CGRectOffset( scrollView.frame, 0, kbHeight*-1);
    }
}
```

However with the WordFlow keyboard (which isn't available anymore) this doesn't work.  I would simply like to make it always use the numberpad from Apple rather than a 3rd party - is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Use the number keypad with what!?  UITextField or UITextView or...

Comment: UITextField sorry.

Comment: textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad; or something similar.  I don't write in Objective-C any more.

Comment: That’s specified in the definition but it’s not always the Apple one.

Comment: On what device?

Comment: iPhone only app